# Reformat Json Object with AWS STS Credentials into AWS Credentials File

Tags: aws-code-deploy, aws-sts, aws-credentials

I'm setting up AWS Code Deploy for an on-premise machine. I'm following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/register-on-premises-instance-iam-session-arn.html) and am using STS temporary credentials.

I can successfully retrieve credentals via:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<acct#>:role/<role-name> --role-session-name <session-name>
```

They are returned in the following format:

```
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "*****",
        "SecretAccessKey": "*****",
        "SessionToken": "*****",
        "Expiration": "2021-03-05T00:55:32Z"
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "*****",
        "Arn": "*****"
    }
}
```

I need to reformat into an AWS credentials file that looks like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=*****
aws_secret_access_key=*****
aws_session_token=*****
```

How can I reformat the json object into the credentials file?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve, transform, and write to file in one line using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<acct#:role/<role-name> --role-session-name <session-name> \
| jq '.Credentials' \
| jq -c '{aws_access_key_id: .AccessKeyId, aws_secret_access_key: .SecretAccessKey, aws_session_token: .SessionToken}' \
| sed -e 's/[{}]//g' -e 's/":"/=/g' -e 's/",/\n/g' -e 's/"//g' \
> <my-file-path>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using `printf` and `--query`

```
printf "
[default]
aws_access_key_id = %s
aws_secret_access_key = %s
aws_session_token = %s
x_security_token_expires = %s" \
    $(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::<acct#>:role/<role-name>" \
      --role-session-name <session-name> \
      --query "Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken,Expiration]" \
      --output text) >> ~/.aws/credentials
```

if you prefere `awk`

```
aws sts assume-role \
--role-arn "arn:aws:iam::<acct#>:role/<role-name>" \
--role-session-name <session-name> \
--query "Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken,Expiration]" \
--output text | awk '
BEGIN {print "[default]"} 
{ print "aws_access_key_id = " $1 } 
{ print "aws_secret_access_key = " $2 } 
{ print "aws_session_token = " $3 } 
{ print "x_security_token_expires = " $4}' >> ~/.aws/credentials
```